# How can firebase users be displayed/ranked according to their distance away from each other with CLLocation?

Tags: swift, firebase-realtime-database

The page should list all users in the firebase database who are within 3 miles. Right now it just lists all the users. In addition to limiting the listing of users to those within 3 miles, it would be good to rank the displayed users, from closest to furthest.

Below is code that already works to display all the users (within 3 miles and further) from the firebase database. All users have a location in firebase - latitude and longitude.

```
            for people in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
                if people.key != thisUsersUid { //do not add this users info to the array
                    let peopleObject = people.value as? [String: AnyObject]
                    let peopleEducation = peopleObject?["Education"] as? String
                    let peopleWhatIamConsideringBuying = peopleObject?["WhatIamConsideringBuying"] as? String
                    let peoplePhotoPosts = peopleObject?["PhotoPosts"]  as? String
                    let peopleimageDownloadURL = peopleObject?["imageDownloadURL"]  as? String
                    let peoplepostID = peopleObject?["postID"] as? String
                    let peoplepeopleWhoLike = peopleObject?["peopleWhoLike"] as? String
                    let peopl = Userx(Education: peopleEducation, WhatIamConsideringBuying: peopleWhatIamConsideringBuying, PhotoPosts: peoplePhotoPosts, imageDownloadURL: peopleimageDownloadURL, postID: peoplepostID, peopleWhoLike: peoplepeopleWhoLike)

                    self.people.append(peopl)

                }
                self.table.reloadData()
            }
        }

        })

        public override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! ViewControllerTableViewCell

    let immy = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UIImageView

    let person: Userx = people[indexPath.row]



    cell.lblName.text = person.Education

    cell.postID = self.people[indexPath.row].postID






    if let PhotoPosts = person.PhotoPosts {
        let url = URL(string: PhotoPosts)
        immy.sd_setImage(with: url)
    }

    return cell

}
```

/Below makes the users locations:

```
  func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let databaseRef = Database.database().reference()
    let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid

    guard let locValue: CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location?.coordinate else { return }
    print("locations = \(locValue.latitude) \(locValue.longitude)")
    latestLocation = ["latitude" : locValue.latitude, "longitude" : locValue.longitude]

    if let locationDictionary = latestLocation {
        databaseRef.child("people").child(uid).child("Coordinates").setValue(locationDictionary)
    }
```

//Update after answer:

```
for people in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {

.......

let peoplepeopleWhoLike = peopleObject?["peopleWhoLike"] as? String
let userId = people.key
let coordSnap = people.childSnapshot(forPath: "Coordinates")
let lat = coordSnap.childSnapshot(forPath: "latitude").value as! CLLocationDegrees
let lon = coordSnap.childSnapshot(forPath: "longitude").value as! CLLocationDegrees
let locCoord = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat, lon)
let coordinates  = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat, longitude: lon)
let peopleLocation = (lat, lon)
print(userId, "coords: \(lat)  \(lon)")
let distance = peopleLocation.distance(to: latestLocation)
let peopl = Userx(Education: peopleEducation, WhatIamConsideringBuying: peopleWhatIamConsideringBuying, PhotoPosts: peoplePhotoPosts, imageDownloadURL: peopleimageDownloadURL, postID: peoplepostID, peopleWhoLike: peoplepeopleWhoLike, distance: distance)
```

Right Now: All users randomly displayed below each other.
What I need: Users within 3 miles displayed underneath each other, from closest to furthest.

Comment: Sort by distance using `distance(from: CLLocation)` from `CoreLocation` library

Comment: In pseudocode how would that look? I assume that would go at:                     "self.people.append(peopl)". Is that right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you need to have the distance of the retrieved users from Firebase, meaning you need to get the object "Coordinates" and store the distance from the current user inside `Userx`.

Then you'd do something like this:

```
for people in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
            if people.key != thisUsersUid { //do not add this users info to the array
                let peopleObject = people.value as? [String: AnyObject]
                let peopleEducation = peopleObject?["Education"] as? String
                let peopleWhatIamConsideringBuying = peopleObject?["WhatIamConsideringBuying"] as? String
                let peoplePhotoPosts = peopleObject?["PhotoPosts"]  as? String
                let peopleimageDownloadURL = peopleObject?["imageDownloadURL"]  as? String
                let peoplepostID = peopleObject?["postID"] as? String
                let peoplepeopleWhoLike = peopleObject?["peopleWhoLike"] as? String

                let peopleLocation = ... // Map user location here using CLLocation(latitude: Double, longitude: Double)
                let distance = peopleLocation.distance(to: thisUserLocation) // thisUserLocation is the one you're getting in latestLocation


                 let peopl = Userx(Education: peopleEducation, WhatIamConsideringBuying: peopleWhatIamConsideringBuying, PhotoPosts: peoplePhotoPosts, imageDownloadURL: peopleimageDownloadURL, postID: peoplepostID, peopleWhoLike: peoplepeopleWhoLike, distance: distance)

                self.people.append(peopl)

            }

            people.sort(by: { (p1, p2) -> Bool in
                return p1.distance < p2.distance
            })

            self.table.reloadData()
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I got peopleLocation to print correctly, albeit using CLLocationDegrees. I get an error: Value of tuple type '(CLLocationDegrees, CLLocationDegrees)' (aka '(Double, Double)') has no member 'distance'. I am posting what I did into the question. Do you maybe know how to fix that?

Comment: Update: Think I got that comment above fixed. Now only "latest location" is in wrong format cause I get Cannot convert value of type '[String : Double]?' to expected argument type 'CLLocation'

Comment: I played around and got that to work as well. Only 1 error remaining in people.sort. It says: Use of unresolved identifier 'peopl'; did you mean 'people'? Do you know how to fix that?

Comment: got that to work by defining     var peopl = [Userx]() . Now via its corrections I need to use:                     self.peopl.sort(by: { (p1, p2) -> Bool in
                        return Unicode.CanonicalCombiningClass(rawValue: UInt8(p1.distance!)) < Unicode.CanonicalCombiningClass(rawValue: UInt8(p2.distance!))
                    })
It doesn't work though. Do you know why maybe?

Comment: For future users: all works except the last sort function. It does calculate the distances though so I am marking this as the correct answer.

Comment: @noname87f Yes, I meant people, sorry. Happy to hear it's working =)

Comment: Thanks again. Are you sure it has to be people because with people it gives error: Value of type 'DataSnapshot' has no member 'sort' . If I then change it to self.people and do the suggested unicode correction I get error: Thread 1: Fatal error: Double value cannot be converted to UInt8 because the result would be greater than UInt8.max